# Can't access variable outside the function even it isn't local

Tags: bash, shell-script, variable

I have simple bash script. My bash version is `GNU bash, version 4.4.20(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)`

```
#!/bin/bash
  
func() {
    nlvar="i'm not local variable"
    local lvar="i'm local variable"
}
echo $nlvar
echo $lvar
```

If I use

```
eval nlvar="i'm not local variable"
```

or

```
export nlvar="i'm not local variable"
```

still nothing is echoed

Comment: Is this the whole script? You defined the function. Where and how do you actually *call* it?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Yes, this is a whole script. I didn't call function. Just wanted to test the scope of variable.

Comment: If you don't call the function there is no scope except the global (undefined) one

Comment: @roaima Got it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't call the function there is no scope except the global (undefined) one:

```
#!/bin/bash
  
func() { :; }    # define a function

echo $nlvar
echo $lvar
```

Defining a function does not execute it, so at the point of execution of the `echo` statements neither variable has been set